# не удается удалить строку по ключевому полю .java

Tags: java

в ходе проверки выполнения не удаляется строка. Помогите исправить ошибку!
код программы

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class jfMyFrame extends JFrame  {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static HashMap<Integer,Smartphone> ListSmart = new HashMap<Integer,Smartphone>();
    private JTable table;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    jfMyFrame frame = new jfMyFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    JButton button_5 = new JButton("\u0418\u0437\u043C\u0435\u043D\u0438\u0442\u044C");

    //создаем стандартную модель
    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public jfMyFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 549, 394);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            }
        });
        scrollPane.setBounds(118, 66, 405, 278);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        //задаем названия столбцов
                dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[] {"Модель", "Раз-р Экрана", "Дисплей","Об-м Флешпам."});

                //наполняем модель данными

                table = new JTable(dtm);
                scrollPane.setViewportView(table);



                final TextField textField = new TextField();
                textField.setBounds(118, 38, 62, 22);
                getContentPane().add(textField);

                Label label = new Label("Model");
                label.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 14));
                label.setBounds(115, 10, 62, 22);
                getContentPane().add(label);

                Label label_1 = new Label("Razmer(diag-l)");//\u0418\u0437\u0433\u043E\u0442\u043E\u0432\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043B\u044C
                label_1.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 14));
                label_1.setBounds(204, 10, 110, 22);
                getContentPane().add(label_1);

                Label label_2 = new Label("Tip_displeya");//\u0427\u0430\u0441\u0442\u043E\u0442\u0430 
                label_2.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 14));
                label_2.setBounds(332, 10, 89, 22);
                getContentPane().add(label_2);

                Label label_3 = new Label("VFlash(GB)");
                label_3.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 14));
                label_3.setBounds(440, 10, 62, 22);
                getContentPane().add(label_3);

                final TextField textField_1 = new TextField();
                textField_1.setBounds(204, 38, 111, 22);
                getContentPane().add(textField_1);

                final TextField textField_2 = new TextField();
                textField_2.setBounds(332, 38, 89, 22);
                getContentPane().add(textField_2);

                final TextField textField_3 = new TextField();
                textField_3.setBounds(440, 38, 83, 22);
                getContentPane().add(textField_3);

                JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("\u0414\u043E\u0431\u0430\u0432\u0438\u0442\u044c");     

                //добавление
                btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if(textField_1.getText().length()!=0){//must use a "final" pharameters 
                            String s1 = new String (textField.getText());
                            Double d2 = new Double(textField_1.getText());
                            String s3 = new String(textField_2.getText());
                            Integer d4 = new Integer(textField_3.getText());

                            Smartphone smrt = new Smartphone(s1,d2, s3, d4);

                            if( ListSmart.containsKey(d4))return;
                             ListSmart.put(d4, smrt);//4 column is key
                            //заполнение таблицы

                                dtm.addRow(new String[]{textField.getText(),
                                        textField_1.getText(),
                                        textField_2.getText(),
                                        textField_3.getText()});
                        }
                    }
                });
                btnNewButton.setBounds(10, 10, 96, 23);
                getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

                //очистка таблицы
            Button button_1 = new Button("\u0423\u0434\u0430\u043B\u0438\u0442\u044C \u0432\u0441\u0435");
                button_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        while(table.getRowCount()>0){
                            dtm.removeRow(0);
                        }
                        ListSmart.clear();
                    }
                });
                button_1.setBounds(10,122, 89, 22);
                getContentPane().add(button_1);

                final TextField textField_4 = new TextField();
                textField_4.setBounds(10, 66, 89, 22);
                getContentPane().add(textField_4);

                Label label_4 = new Label("Razmer(diag-l)");
                label_4.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 12));
                label_4.setBounds(10, 50, 96, 22);
                getContentPane().add(label_4);  

            //удаление строки
                Button button = new Button("\u0423\u0434\u0430\u043B\u0438\u0442\u044C");
                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if(textField_4.getText().length()==0) return;

                        for(int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++){
                            if(dtm.getValueAt(i, 1).equals(textField_1.getText())){
                                Integer in = new Integer(""+dtm.getValueAt(i, 0));
                                ListSmart.remove(in);
                                dtm.removeRow(i);   
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                button.setBounds(10, 94, 89, 22);
                getContentPane().add(button);
}
```

Comment: Предлагаю начать с выдачи всем полям и переменным осмысленных имен. Сейчас у вас ключом таблицы при добавлении является  значение поля `textField_3`, а при удалении - значение нулевого столбца таблицы, в котором лежит значение `textField`.

Answer (score 1):

Основная ошибка заключалась в не совпадении ключевых полей: в коде функции

```
 button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
```

не была заменена строчка

```
Integer in = new Integer(""+dtm.getValueAt(i, 0))
```

на

```
 Double in = new Double(""+dtm.getValueAt(i, 1))
```

, что приводило к ошибке .